# Facing "Unsupported source data type: STRUCT" error with my debezium and kafka integration

Tags: mysql, oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am facing following error while I am integrating debezium and kafka with Oracle RDBMS:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unsupported source data type: STRUCT
```

I am using kafka standalone, configuration for its properties file is as follows:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
plugin.path=kafka_2.12-3.2.3/libs
```

My Oracle Source Connector is as follows:

```
name=connector-test180
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector
tasks.max=1
database.server.name=server1
database.hostname=***.**.0.1
database.port=1521
database.user=username
database.password=password
database.dbname=ORCLCDB
database.pdb.name=ORCLPDB1
database.connection.adapter=logminer
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=schema-changes.inventory
table.include.list=DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER
column.include.list=DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.ID,DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID,DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.STATUS,DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.FIRSTNAME,\
DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.MOBILENUMBER,DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.FATHERNAME,DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.MOTHERNAME,DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.CITY,DEBEZIUM.CUSTOMER.COUNTRY
time.precision.mode=connect
transforms=filter,route
transforms.filter.type=io.debezium.transforms.Filter
transforms.filter.language=jsr223.groovy
transforms.filter.condition=value.source.table == 'CUSTOMER'
transforms.filter.topic.regex=server1.DEBEZIUM.*
transforms.route.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.route.regex=([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)
transforms.route.replacement=$3
```

Kafka connect Sinker is as follows:

```
name=customer-sink139
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=CUSTOMER
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
connection.user=user
connection.password=pass
transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones=false
auto.create=false
insert.mode=upsert
pk.mode=record_value
errors.tolerance=all
pk.fields=ID
auto.evolve=true
```

It is having weired behaviour too, It was working pretty fine till yesterday, and not working today, I havent made any substantial change, and also test it out using my previous backups which were used to working fine. Please help anyone how to resolve it.

Haven't found any resolution to this query, after drilling down through the problem, I suspect that this is all because of field0, this field is ID field in my oracle db having this datatype "ID NOT NULL NUMBER", I don't know why debezium enclosed this in struct with following param:

```
"type":"struct",
                   "fields":[
                      {
                         "type":"int32",
                         "optional":false,
                         "field":"scale"
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"bytes",
                         "optional":false,
                         "field":"value"
                      }
                   ],
```

Comment: Please show raw sample records from the `CUSTOMER` topic from console consumer

Answer (score 0):

I have used following parameter and it gets resolved

```
"converters": "numbertolong"
```